# Order Grouped Barplot in Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart, seaborn

I am trying to figure out how to group a seaborn barplot by one of the groups, but maintain the aggreagated categories. For example,

I have a barplot like this:

```
plt.figure(figsize = (12, 7))
sns.barplot(x = 'x', y = 'y', hue = 'df_tag', data = col_df)
```

[image: grouped barplot by categories]

Alos, I'd like to sort the x-axis by the orange category from smallest to largest, but retain the structure of the categories. (So if 2 on the x-axis has a green, blue and orange bar I want the groups to stay the same, but be ordered by the orange bar from smallest to largest).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To order the columns:

- limit to all rows that have the orange tag
- sort them on y-value
- use the index of the sorted list as index into the original dataframe
- use the x-values of that reordered dataframe

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5],
                   'y': [4, 3, 1, 2, 7, 2, 2, 4, -3],
                   't': [2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2]})

fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 7))
sns.barplot(x='x', y='y', hue='t', data=df, ax=axs[0])
sns.barplot(x='x', y='y', hue='t', data=df, order=df.iloc[df[df['t'] == 2]['y'].sort_values().index]['x'], ax=axs[1])
```

[image: example plot]